# Can't create an exception "ApiError"

Tags: python, try-catch, except, vk

I'm trying to create an automatic messenger using Python and VK API (VK is a russian social network).

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("userID.csv")
allusers = dataset["109"][1:15] 
session = vk_api.VkApi(token="")
vk = session.get_api()
def send_msg(user_id):
  message = "Hello!"
  msg = session.method("messages.send", {"user_id": user_id,
                                         "random_id": 0,
                                         "message": message})
for item in allusers:
    try:
        send_msg(item)
    except ApiError:
        pass
```

Problem is: on VK, some users choose to close their Direct Messages completely, so I've got an error: `[902] Can't send messages to this user due to their privacy settings`
When I want to iterate over a list of users ("allusers"), it stops at the ones with DM lock and doesn't go any further. I can't bypass this error with Try/Except, since it's not part of BaseException, and even if I do add it with class, it doesn't do anything:

```
class ApiError(Exception):
   pass
```

Are there any alternative solutions? Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Post the complete error and is it an HTTP error?

Comment: All exceptions must inherit `Exception`. What do you get when You use `try\except Exception as error`?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The full error is:

'ApiError: [902] Can't send messages to this user due to their privacy settings'

I believe it's the API's error (it's in the documentation: https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exceptions.html). The usual Try/except doesn't help because when I use it, it screams at me that this ApiError is not within BaseException, and it's not allowed to use Try/Except for external exceptions. And, as mentioned above, even if I try to create this exception, the program just ignores it and gives me the same 902 error.